# SVG not rendering IE 11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg

I've the html code [here](http://pastebin.com/fdibzdNa). The svg does not render with IE 11. Can't find out why.

I've added as seen in another place :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I suspect the image is here but not visible. Or it could be the large `data=` which is not interpreted correctly. How to check ?

Comment: check content-type on response from php - currently poss incorrect `Content-Type:text/html` ... you might need to put `data:image/svg+xml;` before the svg, you might need to escape all &gt; @lt; # etc. .. not sure about that though ... never tried. Good luck

Comment: Ok, I've just done that : Content-type: image/svg+xml. The php now returns valid svg, W3C says. But the html page does not display the picture on Chrome nor IE now.

Comment: Hmm ... try losing the text before the svg?

Comment: Sorry. In Chrome, it says "Invalid URL" when doing `data="data:image/svg+xml;http://samuel.levitt.fr/tactik/visu...`

Comment: it will do ... my bad. Have you tried linking to static svg file on the server that has the rendered on it? See if that works.

Comment: I could hotlink a test svg file. Works well. `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="http://samuel.levitt.fr/tactik/test.svg"  style="width:75%;height:60%"></object>`

Comment: tres bien ... now try to attach a static SVG that contains the generated svg from the php. I have to go now. look at response headers in chrome F12 developer tools network tab. Good luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133916/discussion-between-ruskin-and-samueltb).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't include a valid code examples (example link is dead) to fix any ie11 related svg rendering issues. Besides, none of the current answers include a working snippet to be tested in ie11.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What I've done to make it work :

**In the `svg` file :**

1. add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>`
2. add `<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/DTD/svg10.dtd">`
3. remove `height` & `width` properties
4. add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` in the `svg` markup

**In the `html` file :**

5. use an `img` element instead of `object` : `<img src="..." style="width:95%;height:60%" />`

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the issue. With all the steps that you provided, without the 'viewBox' property that was specified by Simon's answer. Still it will never render in IE11, which is essential. I tested it myself.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue and in my case it was because IE requires the `viewBox` attribute to be specified within the SVG for scaling to work correctly, and it was missing from my SVG.

I changed:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="767" height="1024">
```

to:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="767" height="1024" viewBox="0 0 767 1024">
```

The viewBox attribute specifies `<x-origin> <y-origin> <width> <height>`.

This article helped me understand the reasons for this: *[How to scale SVG](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)* [css-tricks.com].

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem when I use the xlink:href attribute to display my svg imgage in IE11, it only display a empty layout without any content.The svg seems like:

```
<svg>
   <symbol id="xxx">
     <g>
       <path>
       </path>
     <g>  
   </symbol>
</svg>
```

when I delete the "g" Tag:

```
<svg>
   <symbol id="xxx">
     <path>
     </path> 
   </symbol>
</svg>
```

it have a correct presentation,
I hope the answer can help other developers to resolve their questions.