# SVG not rendering in IE 11 - Angular 6

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, svg

I am using SVG.js. So I get ready SVG file, I catch div with document.getElementById and I make innerHTML. I had an error but when I used Angular sanitizer error is now not displaying (It was 'access denied'). Everything is working fine on Edge/Chrome except IE 11. I used Angular's polyfills - I uncommented things from polyfills.ts and used npm install in same cases where it is required. I don't know why it is not working.

1. I found informations that IE need viebox - I checked and it is inside my SVG. 
   [topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831355/svg-not-rendering-ie-11)
2. I tried to not innerHTML directly - so I make new div with id and I append it into my empty (always existing) div. Still not working. [topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999998/javascript-innerhtml-is-not-working-for-ie)

Comment: How do you render that SVG? Why don't you just do `<img src="app/img/something-svg"/>` ?

Comment: IE 11 cannot create SVG elements with innerHTML. You'd need to use some other mechanism if you want to support IE.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I get from my API svg file in base64 and I inner it into empty div with specified ID (as I write in question). It is not working correctly only in IE.

Comment: @RobertLongson do you know how to do it in another way? I wthought I can do it when I use Angulars method sanitize() even with SecurityContext.NONE.
https://caniuse.com/#feat=xml-serializer
Says tha IE 11 support this.

Comment: When using IE browser, is there any error (try to use F12 developer tool to check it)? Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes, I have 'Access Denied: Symbol()_g.v6bal5hv84a: undefined, Symbol()_h.v6bal5hv84a: undefined, Symbol(rxSubscriber)_i.v6bal5hv84a: undefined'

Comment: I tried to add this but still not working.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch